# VBscript searching value in 2d array

Tags: vbscript, multidimensional-array

I have 2d array parced from XML.
An example of XML:

```
  <string-array name="array1">
    <field name="City" type="string">Moscow</field>
    <field name="Id" type="number">10</field> (p.s. ID is unique within array)
    <field name="Version" type="number">2</field>
    .......
  </string-array>
```

Parcing it:

```
For i=0 to NodeK.length-1
    array1(0,i)=NodeK(i).getAttribute("name")
    array1(1,i)=NodeK(i).text
Next
```

So 2d array looks like:

```
array1(0,0)="City"
array1(1,0)="Moscow"
array1(0,1)="ID"
array1(1,1)=10
array1(0,2)="Version"
array1(1,2)=2
```

The task is to pick up value for ID so that to use it (in SysId variable) further. The following code does not work properly

```
For i=LBound(array1,1) to Ubound (array1,1)
    For j=Lbound(array1,2) to Ubound(array1,2)
        if j=0 then
            if  array(i,0)="ID"   Then
                SysID=array(i,1)
                MsgBox "New ID is: " & ID, 64
            end if
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Once value (ID=10 in our case) is found loop should exit.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How does it not work properly?  Are you getting an error?  What results are you seeing and what were you expecting?

Comment: Hi, no I'm not getting an error, on the other hand loop's code above picks up nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write your array as a table

```
City    ID  Version
Moscow  10  2
```

Then you see that you need to loop over the 'cols of row 0' to find the key and to address the corresponding 'col of row 1' to get the value.

In code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim array1(1, 2)
array1(0,0)="City"
array1(1,0)="Moscow"
array1(0,1)="ID"
array1(1,1)=10
array1(0,2)="Version"
array1(1,2)=2

Dim sFnd : sFnd = "ID"

Dim i
For i = 0 To UBound(array1, 2)
    WScript.Echo array1(0, i)
    If sFnd = array1(0, i) Then
       WScript.Echo array1(0, i), "=>", array1(1, i)
       Exit For
    End If
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 22862344.vbs
City
ID
ID => 10
```